# How do I get the transfer/transaction history of an erc20 token using web3j givin an address

Tags: web3j, java

I am not sure how to view the the txhistory of an erc20 token for a specific address.

I use a java token wrapper for my erc20 toke as below:

```
public class ERC20 extends Contract {



public static final String FUNC_ALLOWANCE = "allowance";

public static final String FUNC_APPROVE = "approve";

public static final String FUNC_BALANCEOF = "balanceOf";

public static final String FUNC_DECIMALS = "decimals";

public static final String FUNC_DECREASEALLOWANCE = "decreaseAllowance";

public static final String FUNC_INCREASEALLOWANCE = "increaseAllowance";

public static final String FUNC_NAME = "name";

public static final String FUNC_SYMBOL = "symbol";

public static final String FUNC_TOTALSUPPLY = "totalSupply";

public static final String FUNC_TRANSFER = "transfer";

public static final String FUNC_TRANSFERFROM = "transferFrom";

public static final Event APPROVAL_EVENT = new Event("Approval", 
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

public static final Event TRANSFER_EVENT = new Event("Transfer", 
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

protected ERC20(String contractAddress, Handler handler, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
    super(BINARY, contractAddress, handler, contractGasProvider);
}

protected ERC20(String contractAddress, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
    super(BINARY, contractAddress, gasPrice, gasLimit);
}

protected ERC20(String contractAddress, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
    super(BINARY, contractAddress, contractGasProvider);
}

public List<ApprovalEventResponse> getApprovalEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
    List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = extractEventParametersWithLog(APPROVAL_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
    ArrayList<ApprovalEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<ApprovalEventResponse>(valueList.size());
    for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
        ApprovalEventResponse typedResponse = new ApprovalEventResponse();
        typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
        System.out.println(typedResponse.log);
        typedResponse.owner = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        System.out.println(typedResponse.owner);
        typedResponse.spender = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
        System.out.println(typedResponse.spender);
        typedResponse.value = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        System.out.println(typedResponse.value);
        responses.add(typedResponse);
    }
    return responses;
}

public List<TransferEventResponse> getTransferEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
    List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = extractEventParametersWithLog(TRANSFER_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
    ArrayList<TransferEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<TransferEventResponse>(valueList.size());
    for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
        TransferEventResponse typedResponse = new TransferEventResponse();
        typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
        typedResponse.from = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        typedResponse.to = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
        typedResponse.value = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        responses.add(typedResponse);
    }
    return responses;
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> allowance(String owner, String spender) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_ALLOWANCE, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(owner), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(spender)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> approve(String spender, BigInteger amount) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_APPROVE, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(spender), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(amount)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> balanceOf(String account) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_BALANCEOF, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(account)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<BigInteger> balanceOff(String account) {
    final Function function = new Function(FUNC_BALANCEOF, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(account)), 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
    return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> decimals() {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_DECIMALS, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> decreaseAllowance(String spender, BigInteger subtractedValue) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_DECREASEALLOWANCE, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(spender), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(subtractedValue)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> increaseAllowance(String spender, BigInteger addedValue) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_INCREASEALLOWANCE, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(spender), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(addedValue)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> name() {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_NAME, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> symbol() {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_SYMBOL, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> totalSupply() {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_TOTALSUPPLY, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> transfer(String recipient, BigInteger amount) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_TRANSFER, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(recipient), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(amount)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> transferFrom(String sender, String recipient, BigInteger amount) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_TRANSFERFROM, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(sender), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(recipient), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(amount)), 
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}

public static ERC20 load(String contractAddress, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
    return new ERC20(contractAddress, gasPrice, gasLimit);
}

public static ERC20 load(String contractAddress, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
    return new ERC20(contractAddress, contractGasProvider);
}

public static RemoteCall<ERC20> deploy(Handler handler, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider, String name_, String symbol_) {
    String encodedConstructor = FunctionEncoder.encodeConstructor(Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(name_), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(symbol_)));
    return deployRemoteCall(ERC20.class, handler, contractGasProvider, BINARY, encodedConstructor);
}

public static RemoteCall<ERC20> deploy(Handler handler, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit, String name_, String symbol_) {
    String encodedConstructor = FunctionEncoder.encodeConstructor(Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(name_), 
            new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(symbol_)));
    return deployRemoteCall(ERC20.class, handler, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, encodedConstructor);
}

public static class ApprovalEventResponse {
    public Log log;

    public String owner;

    public String spender;

    public BigInteger value;
}

public static class TransferEventResponse {
    public Log log;

    public String from;

    public String to;

    public BigInteger value;
}
}
```

Comment: which version of web3j have you used to create that wrapper, I think some methods which return Flowable<....> are missing